# Why does find_package(MPI) generate a warning message?

Tags: cmake, mpi

I'm using CMake 3.22.0-rc2. When I run:

```
find_package(MPI)
```

I get the warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/versions/cmake/3.22.0-rc2/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)
  does not match the name of the calling package (MPI).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/versions/cmake/3.22.0-rc2/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:88 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /opt/versions/cmake/3.22.0-rc2/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:270 (include)
  examples/multi-gpu-programming-models/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I realize I can suppress this error, but - does it have anything to do with what I've got in my `CMakeLists.txt` or is this some sort of internal CMake (semi-)bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning has recently been fixed in https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/56d949f05f37c65401825a30be0d39bd152cc33c.

It was [incorrect inclusion](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/0723b2c93590b45a9f551c2ece2d2b80a2a2ae1d) of module `FindPkgConfig.cmake` via

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FindPkgConfig.cmake)
```

With such inclusion the call to `find_package_handle_standard_args` performed inside `FindPkgConfig.cmake` is interpreted as from the `FindMPI.cmake` module, because the latest `find_package` call has `MPI` argument instead of `PkgConfig`.

All modules like `FindXXX.cmake` should be included via `find_package`:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
```

Comment: How far bag does this issue go? Also, could I trouble you to have a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69876950/1593077)? I suspect it might also be a CMake bug.

Comment: With simple `find_package(MPI)` you hardly would get any problems aside from the warning. But with a call like `find_package(MPI VERSION 1.2.3 COMPONENTS foo bar)` the module `FindPkgConfig.cmake` would interpret VERSION and COMPONENTS as its own, which could lead to not-found errors. As for the warning itself, it is for detect wrong `FindXXX.cmake` scripts which sets `YYY_FOUND` variable instead of `XXX_FOUND`. As far as I remember, `FindEigen.cmake` is (was?) one of such incorrect scripts: it sets `EIGEN_FOUND` variable instead of `Eigen_FOUND`.